# Describe a graph through logic

Tags: graph-theory, logic, computer-science

At the moment I'm in need to learn how to describe a graph through a logic statement such as:

$$
\forall x\forall y(r(x,y) \to \lnot s(y,x) \land \lnot s(y,x)) \land \exists (s(z,z) \land \lnot r(z,z)$$

Where can I find a paper, document or any other useful source to learn how to draw a graph from such a formula and (eventually) viceversa?

Comment: Are $r$ and $s$ arbitrary binary relations or do they have some specific meaning? Are $x$, $y$ and $z$ vertices of the graph?

Comment: Arbitrary relations. As far as I understand x, y and z should be vertices of the graph.

Comment: Is that particular formula intended to carry a particular graph theoretic meaning?  A graph can be represented by two dimensional adjacency matrix, and you can represent that by a binary predicate, where $E(u,v)$ if there is an edge from $u$ to $v$.  You might want to add some axioms to fix the set of nodes, such as $\forall x.(x = u_1 \lor \dotsb \lor x = u_n)$.  Graph theoretic properties should be fairly straightforward to express after that.

Comment: The main reason I'm asking this is because of Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game. A formula like the one described in the question is given and my task is to determine two "interpretation" of the formula (defined as Language L) one which satisfy the formula and one which doesen't. As far as I've understand (very little actually) those two interpretation of the language should be graphs derived by the formula. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For definition of *graphs* in *first-order* language and *Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games*, you can see :

> Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521518121) (2011).

A *graph* [see page 35-on] :

> is a pair $\mathcal G = (V, E)$ where $V$ is a set of elements called *vertices* and $E$ is an anti-reflexive symmetric binary relation on $V$ called the *edge* relation.

See page 38 :

> **Example 4.5** : $\exists x \forall y \forall z((\lnot yEx \land \lnot zEx \land \lnot(y = z)) \rightarrow \exists x(yEx \land zEx))$
>
> is true in a graph if and only if the graph has a vertex such that outside its neighbors any two distinct vertices have a common neighbor.